# my api is returning invalid JSON nodejs in post request while fectching

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am sending a post request in my next js app API (API is for updating address)

this is my fetching API code

```
async function handleSubmit() {

const data = { deliveryAddress, landmark, pincode, district, block, state }
const userID = localStorage.getItem("userID")

for (let item in data) {
  let element = data[item];
  if (element == "") {
    toast.error(`${item} field must be filled`, {
      position: "top-center",
      autoClose: 3000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined
    });
    break;
  }

}
console.log("above try");
console.log({ "address": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), "userid": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( userID)) });
try {
  console.log("hello");
  let res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/updateaddress`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: [{ "address": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), "userid": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userID)) }]
  })
  let parsedResponse = await res.json()
  console.log("response", parsedResponse);
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

}

and this code is returning an invalid Json error
this code line `body: [{ "address": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), "userid": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userID)) }]`

this is what I got when I console.log my response body `console.log({ "address": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), "userid": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( userID)) });`

***image of console error and the above-logged coder***
[image: this is the console image of error and the above-logged code]

**Summary**
I am getting a invalid JSON error but i think my JSON is correct and nothing wrong with api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting a invalid JSON error

Well, your JSON is invalid…

> ```
> body: [{ "address": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), "userid": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userID)) }]
> ```

That's an array, not JSON. You need to pass JSON to the body property.

Also `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` does nothing useful in this context (since it is useful to deep clone simple objects and you don't mutate the value afterwards) so don't do that.

```
body: JSON.stringify([{ "address": data, "userid": userID }])
```

---

… but a 401 status means [Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401).

Comment: can you please tell me how to destructure it by using requset.body